# How to unit test a private variable?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

Consider a linkedlist class and I maintain 2 private variables 1. firstNode and 2. lastNode. These variables are only for internal use thus, not exposed via getters. I want to test that operations do modify these 2 variables as expected. Eg: eliminating duplicate in sorted linkedlist should change the last node if last node was a duplicate.

1. Should I add an explicit getter only for unit tests?
2. If not then how to access the value of private unexposed variables ?

Comment: You should consider testing the *observable effect* of that variable's value on the public interface.

Comment: Hard to say from here what you should do, but the need to test a private variable should mean you need to change your design.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Not true IMHO (and according to classic TDD practices).  He should be able to write the test even before the implementation exists.  Then he should be able to make the test work with a quick'n'dirty implementation.  And then he should be able to improve his design without breaking the test.

Comment: @herman, well yes, but IMNSHO that would mean there was testable oberservable behaviour from the get go, or it would never become private, so  I think my comment stands.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Indeed, but for a linked list implementation I would think there would always be observable behaviour.  In fact in most cases there should be if there is no port crossed (e.g. data written to DB, GUI updated etc).  But indeed changing the design can be necessary to mock/stub a DAO or web service call.  If you find yourself often changing the design to make something testable, it could mean the granularity of your tests is too small (like if you're trying to test a class in isolation by mocking out all dependencies, regardless if they cross a port or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No.
2. You don't.  You would be coupling your test to your implementation.  If you were to refactor your implementation, you would want to have the confidence that if your test keeps working without having to modify it, you didn't break anything.

Think about what will go wrong (i.e. which part of the contract will be violated) if those variables are not correctly updated.  Write a test for that, prove that it fails when it should, then make sure it doesn't fail.

Comment: so don't do it one way because the things you use could change, instead do it another way where the things you are using can change. (i don't get why you shouldn't test privates)

Comment: @puser Your private variables could change without causing a change to the outside, because e.g. you are just restructuring some code.  In that case you don't want a have to fix a test.  On the contrary, you want the tests to provide the insurance that there really is change to the outside.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By change without causing a change to the outside, do you mean the name of the variable could change? if so, refactoring can refactor the reference to it in your unit tests. if not can you explain what you meant. thank you

Comment: @puser Anything could happen during refactoring: the variable may be moved to another class to which the tested operations delegate, the type of the variable may be refactored into two or more types, the contract of that type may have changed so that different methods (or the same but with different parameters) should be called on the variable, or simply a `String` or `int` could be replaced by an `enum`.  So you can first make your test work with 'dirty' code, which you can then restructure internally in any way while using the  original test to verify that you don't break anything.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't test private variables, only things that are public.  Testing private data is testing implementation details which are very fragile.  If you were to ever change your implementation, those tests would fail or no longer compile.

Instead, write tests that only test the public API.  In your example of using a linked list, your tests should modify the list and then walk over the structure using the public methods to go from node to node to make sure all the nodes are correct.

Comment: +1 for stressing that it's the public API that should be tested

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it.  You should be testing the *behaviour* of your linked list, not its *implementation*.  Work out how your linked list should behave in various circumstances, and derive test cases from its expected behaviour.  If you find yourself writing a test case that needs to look into the implementation of a class (including its private members), then your test is not actually ensuring the correctness of the class's behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make it package-level getters.  The get functions won't be exposed but you can still check.

Comment: sounds reasonable but is this typically followed in industry ?

Comment: I have found that true unit testing is only done in about half the companies that I have worked for.  Those that do unit test, do so with very little formality.  Google is the only one that I know of that forces a very high quality of unit testing.  Normally, the code writer is free to make whatever things are needed for their own unit testing.

Comment: I would try other options before relaxing access modifiers.  You should almost never need to do that.